# Based on Genesis 7 verse 20 - Did 29,054.2 Feet (29,031.7 Feet + 22.5 Feet) of גֶּ֖שֶׁם "Rain" fall during הַמַּבּ֣וּל The-Flood?

Tags: genesis, flood

Genesis 7:14 tells us Ha-Geshem הַגֶּ֖שֶׁם "The-Rain" was on the earth forty days and nights (וַיְהִ֥י הַגֶּ֖שֶׁם עַל־הָאָ֑רֶץ אַרְבָּעִ֣ים י֔וֹם וְאַרְבָּעִ֖ים לָֽיְלָה), and the sea level reached 15 Cubits (22.5 Feet) above all mountains on earth in Genesis 7:20 :

[Bereshit | Genesis 7:20]
"Fifteen cubits above did the waters prevail, **and the mountains were covered up**." (חֲמֵ֨שׁ עֶשְׂרֵ֤ה אַמָּה֙ מִלְמַ֔עְלָה גָּֽבְר֖וּ הַמָּ֑יִם וַיְכֻסּ֖וּ הֶֽהָרִֽים)

Now if the height of Mount Everest (29,031.7-Feet) is considered in the rising sea levels of "The-Flood" הַמַּבּ֣וּל Ha-Mabul : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest

**Did 29,054.2-Feet (29,031.7 Feet + 22.5 Feet) of גֶּ֖שֶׁם "Rain" fall during הַמַּבּ֣וּל The-Flood, based on Genesis 7 verse 20?**

Comment: This question is predicted on the assumption that the height of Mt Everest is static - that is false - Everest is almost certainly MUCH higher now than before the flood, and still rising.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is reasoned out. However, you need to consider scripture, not just reasoning…

**GEN 7:11** *In the six hundredth year of Noah’s life, in the second month, on the seventeenth day of the month, on that day all the fountains of the great deep burst forth, and the windows of the heavens were opened.*

This verse even in a simple reading reflects that at least *some* of the waters were ‘sourced’ from *underneath* the earth. Even today’s science acknowledges that there are waters under the earth - and these are significant. (Substantial).

That is, the earth wasn’t totally flooded by rain. This would almost (totally?) be impossible. Second, pre flood there was a canopy over the earth.

**GEN 1:7** *And God made the firmament and separated the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament*

And that may? have also had a role. Next, you are assuming that Everest was ‘then’ as it is today. The Himalayan’s are a tectonically produced mountain range, and *exactly* when that ‘movement’ took place is unknown. Some say the flood itself was a factor in tectonic movement.

So, the answer to your Q, “**Did 29054.2-Feet (29,031.7 Feet + 22.5 Feet) of גֶּ֖שֶׁם "Rain" fall during הַמַּבּ֣וּל The-Flood, based on Genesis 7 verse 20?**” is No!

Answer (score 2):

This is a question skeptics like to ask, but they usually do not consider that the very mountains by which they try to estimate the height of the waters were pushed up to such lofty altitudes by the techtonic plate movements that continued *after* the Flood.  When the Flood occurred, Mt. Everest was not yet a mountain.

The Biblical evidence of the techtonic plate movement is found in a brief verse following the account of the Flood.

> And unto Eber were born two sons: the name of one was Peleg; for in
> his days was the earth divided; and his brother's name was Joktan.
> (Genesis 10:25, KJV)

Until this point in time, even scientists will agree that the earth once consisted of one large continent, which they have named "Pangea."  But the Bible tells us when the division of the earth occurred, and this happened about 100 years *after* the Flood.

Evidence that Everest was not always so tall is also abundant in the rock layers of the mountain itself--for it is [full of fossils](https://www.aap.com.au/nothing-fishy-about-ancient-marine-fossils-on-everest/) of fish, shellfish, and other water-dwelling creatures, even above 20,000 feet.